# How to override existing directive over another

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This is my directive

```
myDirectives.directive('registerSuccess', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'></div>",
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {

            scope.registerSuccess = function(data) {
                alert(data);
                var msg = "Database "+data+" got registered"
                console.log(elm.attr('style'));
                elm.text((elm.html()||msg));
                elm.removeAttr('style');
                $timeout(function(){
                    elm.hide();
                }, 8000);
            };

        }
    };
});
```

It only displays the first data name but when 2nd data is registered it cannot display the 2nd name hence it displays the 1st data name only

In my controller

```
$scope.registerSuccess(data.dbName);
```

In my html

```
<register-success style='display:none;'></register-success>
```

Comment: Where do you call $scope.registerSuccess(data.dbName);? I mean, the directive's controller?

Answer (score 0):

When you call $scope.registerSuccess function at second time, elm.html function(in your link function) return valid html which you set at first time. Therefore you always see the 1st message even if "msg" variable have the 2nd name.